# How to extract only Numbers from the value $1,632.50 (BigQuery)

Tags: python, sql, regex, google-bigquery

I would like to extract only numbers before the decimal point.

for example -> $1,632.50

I would like it to return 1632.

the current regex I have (**r'[0-9]+'**) doesn't fetch the correct value if there is a comma associated with the value.

example --> $1,632.50 it returns 1

but for ---> $500.00 it returns 500 
It works fine in this case

I am new to regex. Any help is appreciated

PS: I am currently using **Bigquery** and 
I only have REGEX_EXTRACT AND REGEX_REPLACE to work with.

Most of the solutions here work on a normal python script but I still can't get it to work on BigQuery

Comment: maybe you can do that without regex, with `str.replace` or `str.split`.

Comment: REPLACE((REGEXP_EXTRACT(amount , r'([\d,]+)')),',','') 

This works. I guess there are better alternatives as suggested here but I'm okay with this for now

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks!
I was trying to find out how to accept the correct answer. I am new to SO:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'\..*|[^0-9]', '')
```

As you can see here is only one REGEXP_REPLACE does the work

You can test, play with it using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT '$1,632.50' AS str UNION ALL
  SELECT  '$500.00'
)
SELECT 
  str, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'\..*|[^0-9]', '') AS extracted_number
FROM t
```

with result

```
Row str         extracted_number     
1   $1,632.50   1632     
2   $500.00     500
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches the first *group* of digits. It stops at comma. Seems difficult to do that only with one regex.

So search for digits *and* comma, then replace comma by nothing using `str.replace`, convert to integer:

```
import re

s = "$1,632.50"

result = int(re.search("([\d,]+)",s).group(1).replace(",",""))
```

(doesn't work for `$.50`, but you can use other tricks, like for instance replace `$` by `$0` before starting to make sure that there's a 0 after the `$`)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in Python without regexp is to extract the part of the string that falls between the dollar sign and decimal, then use `replace` to remove any commas found inside.

```
s = "My price is: $1,632.50"
extracted = s[s.find('$')+1:s.find('.')].replace(',', '')
print(extracted)
```

Here's the same sort of thing with a regexp:

```
# Look for the first dollar sign, followed by any mix of digits and 
# commas, and stop when you've found (if any) character after that
# which isn't a comma or digit.  So both "$1,234.50!" and "$1,234!"
# for example should give back "1234".
result = re.search("(\$)([\d,]+)([^,\d]*)", s)
print(re.sub(',', '', result.group(2)))
```

`re.sub` here isn't much different than using a string `.replace`, but it's technically a way to do it using "only" regexps.

Comment: if the string doesn't have cents like `$500`, `s.find(".")` returns -1.

Comment: The OP said "before the decimal point", implying that it's assumed to be there.  It still works if the string itself is "$500", since the numbers are at the end anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is just to use `re.sub`.

Example:

```py
import re

result = re.sub(r'[^\d.]', '', '$1,234.56')
```

This replaces all of the non-numbers and a `.` with nothing, leaving just numbers including the decimal.

Comment: But this example returns "1234.56" for me, not "1234".

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work pretty well: `r'(\d{,3})?[.,]?(\d{3})?'`. Testing it out:

```
import re
pattern = r'(\d{,3})?[.,]?(\d{3})?'
tests = ['1,234.50',
         '456.7',
         '12']
for t in tests:
    print(''.join([g for g in re.match(pattern, t).groups() if g is not None]))
# 1234
# 456
# 12
```

Unfortunately you run into an issue with repeated groupings. It appears that the `re` package does not support repeating subgroup captures. In those cases, you should probably use a string replace.

Breaking down the regex:

```
pattern = """ (          # begin capture group
               \d{,3}    # up to three digits
              )          # end capture group
              ?          # zero or one of these first groups of digits
              [.,]?      # zero or one period or comma (not captured)
              (          # begin capture group inside of the non-capture group
               \d{3}     # exactly three digits
              )          # end capture group
              ?          # zero or one of these
          """
```

You could probably simplify this a bit, but the big thing is you capture each group of three digits (treating the first differently because it can be up to three) separated by optional commas. To put them all together, simply use `''.join([g for g in re.match(pattern, my_string).groups() if g is not None])` as in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `[0-9]+` matches 1+ times a digit and will not match a comma. It is also not taking the dollar sign into account.

What you might do is match a dollar sign, capture in a group 1+ digits and an optional part that matches a comma and 1+ digits. Then, from that group replace the comma with an empty string.

```
\$(\d+(?:,\d+)?)
```

Explanation

- `\$` Match $
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:,\d+)?` Optional capturing group that matches a comma and 1+ digits
- `)` Close Capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hMqk0Y/1)

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, you can combine the two functions:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_extract(str, '[^.]+'), '[^0-9]', '')
from (select '$1,632.50' as str) x
```